# Poloniex api 'Total must be at least 0.0001' error

Tags: python, poloniex

I am writing python bot for poloniex.

```
polo = poloniex.Poloniex('key', 'secret')
polo.sell('BTC_ETH', 0.043, 0.01)
polo.buy('BTC_ETH', 0.043, 0.01)
```

Buy and sell functions raises error 'Total must be at least 0.0001.'

Why poloniex return this error? The balance is sufficient for the transaction. A similar transaction through web interface is successful.

Comment: I have the same problem, but only when attempting to sell various altcoins. I am very certain that this could be an error on their side, as the moment the bug occurred, I went to Poloniex and managed to sell the altcoin with the very same parameters via their web interface.

Comment: have you figured out how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The third parameter "amount" is not in BTC, but in your altcoin, so the correct code is:

```
polo.sell('BTC_ETH', 0.043, (0.01*0.043))
polo.buy('BTC_ETH', 0.043, (0.01*0.043))
```

Comment: I think that should be a divide not a multiply in the 3rd arguement